# pass javascript date to input Type of c# "datetime"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, datetime

with asp.net, how can pass javascript date into input with type datetime.

input tag:

```
<input asp-for="EndingDate"  id="enddate" class="form-control input-sm" />
```

and the attempt to send javascript date to the input value:

```
const d = new Date("2015-03-25");
$('#enddate').val(d.toJSON());
```

Comment: so you want to use jquerry to assign values from c# to html elemets? you can do it with c# js interoop

Answer (score 0):

Did you try below.

```
const d = new Date("2015-03-25");
$('#enddate').val(d);
```

This will assign date time to asp.net text filed. But no-masking and calendar. If the field have calendar then you need to call calendar initiate method after this.

```
   $("#enddate").datepicker();
```

The form post should work as it is.

Comment: You mean, datepicker from jqueryui?

Comment: It depends on which datepicker or calendar library you are using. Here is the jquery datepicker as an example. If you use bootstrap calendar then initiate it after binding the value to the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let endDate = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10); //Get Date part
$('#enddate').attr('value',endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `EndingDate` is type of DateTime, it will generate the input with `type="datetime-local"`.

Change your code below:

```
var isoStr = new Date("2015-03-25").toISOString();
$('#enddate').val(isoStr.substring(0,isoStr.length-1));
```

Comment: hello rena, i would like to thank you first. to be honest i solved the issue without using javascript ( used another approach ). i will try your answer and tell you